# How to mock a method call in a constructor?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4

I have class **class1**, which has 2 member variables:

```
classA
{
    private Boolean isEnable;
    private Config config;
   
    public classA(final Config config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        isEnable = config.getEnablingStatus();
    }

    public classB fun()
    {
        // Do something!
        // Return an object of classB!
    }
}
```

I want to test the method **fun**, so I will have to write a test-class and a test method for that. But, how do I mock the method call **config.getEnablingStatus()**, while creating an object of type **classA** in the test class?

I am thinking of doing something like this [see the below piece of code].Is it correct? But what is the right way to do it?

TestClassForClassA:

```
TestClassForClassA
{
    private Boolean isEnable;
    
    @Mock
    private Config config;
   
    @InjectMocks
    classA objA = new classA(config);

    @Before
    public void init() 
    {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    public void test1Fun()
    {
        // Does doing this, put the value of isEnable as true in the objA for this test?
        isEnable = true; 
        
        // Here write the code to test the method fun().
    }

    public void test2Fun()
    {
        // Does doing this, put the value of isEnable as false in the objA for this test?
        isEnable = false; 
        
        // Here write the code to test the method fun().
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You need to stub the method you want. `when(config.getEnablingStatus()).thenReturn(…)`.

Comment: Can't you just set `isEnabled` to true or false, depending on what you want to test?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Where do I put that stub? In the init()? Or in the test1fun() and test2fun() methods?

Comment: why do you need that call in the constructor anyway? any time you need to check that flag, you can just call that method.

Comment: @Stultuske that method internally calls the database, so it would be inefficient to call it multiple times.

Comment: *"that method internally calls the database"* **--** a constructor should only initialize (final) member variables of the object. It should not do any business logic or sophisticated checks. Especially it should not call methods on other object that could cause exceptions in any way. So you should to the call ro the database **before** the constructor call and pass the result into the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use @InjectMocks

Try something like this

```
public class TestClassForClassA {

    @Mock
    private Config config;

    private ClassA objA;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1Fun() {
        Mockito.when(config.getEnablingStatus()).thenReturn(true);
        objA = new ClassA(config);
        ClassB objB = objA.fun();
        assertTrue(objB.isEnabled());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2Fun() {
        Mockito.when(config.getEnablingStatus()).thenReturn(false);
        objA = new ClassA(config);
        ClassB objB = objA.fun();
        assertFalse(objB.isEnabled());
    }

}
```